# Do any characters in Arthur have family members who aren't the same type of animal?

Tags: arthur

In [*Arthur*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_(TV_series)), Arthur is an aardvark as are his parents and sisters. Buster is a rabbit as is his mom and dad. Does any character have family members who aren't the same type of animal? I'm especially wondering if any of them have biological family members who are different types of animals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. D.W.'s best friend, [Emily](https://arthur.fandom.com/wiki/Emily), is a rabbit whose mother is a rabbit and whose father is a monkey. Another of D.W.'s classmates, [James](https://arthur.fandom.com/wiki/James_MacDonald), is a rabbit whose mother is a dog and father is (presumably) a rabbit.

Note that neither of these characters appear to have bi-racial characteristics; as far as is evident, they are the same species as one of their parents rather than being a mixed species.

Comment: I assume that it's not been established whether or not these are biological parents? Like, there wasn't a plot about these kids being adopted or anything?

Comment: That's a great question ... as far as I know it isn't stated either way, so it's conceivable there could have been an adoption, or the parent of a different species could be a step-parent, etc.